# select sub dataset with specific conditions without using apply & subset functions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have dataset as below

`df<-data.frame(name=c("alicia","samantha","john","jessie"), age=c(40,-23,30,28), income=c(100, 50, 120,60))`

What I am trying to do is to select dataset which does not have negative value and values less than 100.
I've tried

`df[(df[,c(2:3)]>=0&df[,(2:3)]<=100),]`

But I could not delete the values which is greater than 100 and I got many `'NA's`, as below.

```
 #       name age income
 # 1    alicia  40    100
 # 3      john  30    120
 # 4    jessie  28     60
 # NA     <NA>  NA     NA
 # NA.1   <NA>  NA     NA
 # NA.2   <NA>  NA     NA
```

I would like to do this work without `apply` and `subset` functions.

The final dataset that I would like to have is

```
#    name  age income  
# 1 alicia 40  100
# 2 jessie 28  60
```

By the way, someone can explain me why I got additional lines with `NAs` with my code  `df[(df[,c(2:3)]>=0&df[,(2:3)]<=100),]`  ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want. We need to evaluate it column by column.

```
df[df$age > 0 & df$age <= 100 &  df$income > 0 & df$income <= 100, ]
#     name age income
# 1 alicia  40    100
# 4 jessie  28     60
```

Or you can do this if this is easier. We used `rowSums` here because if each row satisfied your conditions, the sum would be two.

```
df[rowSums(df[,c(2:3)] >= 0 & df[,(2:3)] <= 100) == 2L, ]
#     name age income
# 1 alicia  40    100
# 4 jessie  28     60
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df,  age >=0 & income <= 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using base R is not a strict requirement `dplyr` can be your friend:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    filter(age >= 0
           & income <= 100

#     name age income
# 1 alicia  40    100
# 2 jessie  28     60
```